# Probability of drawing 4 unique colors from a barrel of marbles that have 12 different colors

Tags: probability

I was eating jellybeans today and thought of this math problem!

Bag contains infinite marbles.  Each marble is one of 12 possible colors (blue, red, yellow, etc)  I choose 4 marbles.  What is the probability they are all different colors?

Here is my incorrect first attempt:

$$P(match) = \frac{1}{12}\frac{2}{12}\frac{3}{12} = \frac{6}{1728}$$

$$P(No match) = 1-\frac{6}{1728}  = \frac{1718}{1728}$$

This felt way too high, and I realized this was actually measuring the odds of having a match for every draw, and not just any single match.

Comment: Having drawn the first, what is the chance the second doesn't match?  Having drawn two different, what is the chance the third matches neither?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this question in terms of the colors: We choose the $4$ distinct colors to appear in the draw in $\binom{12}{4}$ ways, and then arrange the colors in $4!$ ways.

Note the one-one correspondence between these colors and the marbles. Then divide by $12^4$, the total number of ways to assign colors.

Probability comes out to be $\frac{55}{96}$, a much more reasonable answer.

Comment: Or simply $\frac{11}{12}\cdot\frac{10}{12}\cdot\frac9{12}=\frac{55}{96}$'

Comment: Nice out of the box thinking!   What do you do for work??

Comment: Love @bof contribution, as well.   Odds of a new color on each pick.   I was on the right track.  Thx